# Error configuring broker SSL environment for ActiveMQ 5.17

Tags: bash, apache2, ssl

Hoping this issue has arisen previously and has a simple fix.
I have installed ActiveMQ 5.17 pretty seamlessly thanks to the Apache docs.

However, I do not see much on SSl config for ActiveMQ.

It's a realtively simple problem but I cannot figure it out as of yet.

When I use this doc - https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl

I come to a section setting up an environment export.

```
export ACTIVEMQ_SSL_OPTS = -
Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/broker.ks -
Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

However, I am getting errors back.

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/broker.ks': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password': not a valid identifier
```

I get this with or without changing the correct password and path.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; and thus there is currently nothing on-topic for this site?  Why ask here? What OS/release are you using?

Comment: The specific error you mention is due to improper whitespace in the shell variable assignment

Comment: Yes thank you. You are correct.
Can anyone suggest the best doc to use for java key store?
Apache's is confusing to me. Why do I need a client? Granted I don't know what the Message Queue is for other than being a logic file queue that processes data in a proper manner usually to a DB.